# User input C programming

Tags: c, user-input

I am trying to run a C program that requires the user input.

The program is supposed to prompt the user to enter certain words and I am supposed to search for those words in a data structure.

so the command line is supposed to look like this:

prompt>

the user will enter multiple words to search and I need access to each one of those words separately. AFter the program is done executing on those words, the program needs to restart and keep running until the user types in "quit" in the prompt.

Ex: 
prompt> ..... (program will run based on the words input)

prompt> .....

prompt> .....

prompt> quit

I dont know how to prompt for user input in C, can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for 'prompt for User Input in c' gives you Lots of tutorials

Comment: Show us what code you have got.

Answer (score 9):

1) vi hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 80

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char a_word[MAX_LEN];

  printf ("Enter a word: ");
  scanf ("%s", a_word);
  printf ("You entered: %s\n", a_word);
  return 0;
}
```

2) gcc -G -Wall -pedantic -o hello hello.c

3) ./hello

NOTE:

The syntax will be different depending on your platform and compiler.

Here's another link:

- http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-first-c-program-hello-world

Comment: Do not use `scanf` - there are better options - http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 0):

This might help 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_input_and_output

basically scanf